# Refresh Token request returning new refresh token?

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm using Oauth2 on my own Web API and ASP.NET C# to consume that API on a web app.  On my web app, I'm making HttpWebRequests.  When my access token expires, I'm calling a method "RefreshToken" that makes a request to get a new access token.  This works beautifully without issue...except that the response I get back contains a new refresh token???  I was expecting just the new access token.  I didn't even think this was possible without passing credentials again, but my grant_type=refresh_token is somehow generating a new refresh token, and it has me concerned.

Comment: My grant_type=password AND grant_type=refresh_token responses both look like this:

Comment: Have you [seen this](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/)?

Answer (score 2):

Please see [this post](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/) by Taiseer Joudeh (which is a phenomenal series of posts by the way).

You will find in the SimpleRefreshTokenProvider's CreateAsync method, the refresh token is deleted and re-created which provides "sliding expiration". If you don't want a new refresh token each time don't delete/recreate.

Here is the line of code I'm talking about:

```
var result = await tokenRepository.AddRefreshToken(token);
```

AddRefreshToken actually deletes and re-creates the token as seen here:

```
public async Task<bool> AddRefreshToken(AspNetRefreshToken token)
{
    var existingToken = _context.AspNetRefreshTokens.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Subject == token.Subject && r.ClientId == token.ClientId);

    if (existingToken != null)
    {
        await RemoveRefreshToken(existingToken);
    }

    _context.AspNetRefreshTokens.Add(token);

    return await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
}
```

So again, without seeing your code I would say its working as expected. If you don't want sliding expiration, don't have the provider re-create the refresh token each time.